# How do I use get and set methods in c++ with an object that is initialised with new

Tags: c++, object, setter, getter

Im trying to use get and set methods within c++ with an object that is initialised with new

```
Person *Person1 = new Person;
        string first;
        string family; 
        string ID;
        int birth;
```

anyone any idea how I do this?

Comment: You should really **study**,

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `Person` has member functions like `getFirst()` you would use the dereference operator (`->` or `*`) like this:

```
Person1->getFirst(); // equivalent to (*Person1).getFirst()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the setters and getters in your class, as well as you should define your members there

something like:

class person{

public:

```
person(){}

~person(){}

here put your getter and setter like...
void setFirst(...) { .... }
string getFirst() { return ... }
...
```

private:

```
string first;
string family;
string ID;
int birth;
```

}